# WPF: User Control access Style via Dependency Property

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, dependency-properties

I have created a Style for a Button with an Image:

```
    <Style x:Key="StyleButtonBase" TargetType="Button">
    <Style.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="../Sizes/Sizes.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="../Colors/Brushes.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="../Fonts/Fonts.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="../Images/Images.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Style.Resources>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource BrushButtonActive}" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource BrushForegroundLight}" />
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource FontFamilyDefault}" />
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{StaticResource DoubleFontSizeStandard}" />
    <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <Border
                    Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                    BorderBrush="{StaticResource BrushBorder}"
                    BorderThickness="{StaticResource ThicknessBorder}"
                    CornerRadius="{StaticResource CornerRadius}">
                    <Image Source="{StaticResource IconIcon}" Stretch="None" />
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource BrushButtonPressed}" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Now I Want to create a User-Control which only consists of a Button with this style and a Dependency Property to set the Button Image. The XAML part of my user control looks like this:

```
<UserControl
x:Class="HH.HMI.ToolSuite.ResourceLib.Controls.ButtonSmall">

<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="../Styles/Buttons.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>


<Button Style="{StaticResource StyleButtonBase}" Width="{StaticResource DoubleWidthButtonSmall}" Height="{StaticResource DoubleHeightControls}">
</Button></UserControl>
```

The code behind of my user-control looks like this:

```
public partial class ButtonSmall : UserControl, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ButtonSmall()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ButtonImageProperty
        = DependencyProperty.Register("ButtonImage", typeof(ImageSource), typeof(TextOutput), new PropertyMetadata(null, OnButtonImagePropertyChanged));

    private static void OnButtonImagePropertyChanged(DependencyObject dependencyObject,
           DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ButtonSmall temp = dependencyObject as ButtonSmall;
        temp.OnPropertyChanged("ButtonImage");
        temp.OnButtonImagePropertyChanged(e);
    }

    private void OnButtonImagePropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ButtonSmallImage.Source = ButtonImageSource;
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    public ImageSource ButtonImageSource
    {
        get { return (ImageSource)GetValue(ButtonImageProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ButtonImageProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

In my other user-controls i usually access an element in the user control itself like:

```
xamlname.text = text
```

Now i haven't a named element in my xaml code of the user-control. Instead i have the named element in the style, which i reference in the user control. How can access this throug my code behind?

Answer (score 1):

If I were you I'd subclass Button and create a new class (just a .cs file) like so:

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;

namespace MyProject
{
    public class IconButton : Button
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty ButtonImageProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ButtonImage", typeof(ImageSource), typeof(IconButton),
                  new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(new BitmapImage(), FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender));

        public ImageSource ButtonImage
        {
            get { return (ImageSource)GetValue(ButtonImageProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ButtonImageProperty, value); }
        }
    }
}
```

This means you can now reference the property. Otherwise, because your button is just a regular button (with only a regular button's properties; no image), your style doesn't know about your new image property which it expects a Button to have. Don't forget to update your style's TargetType's to point to IconButton.

If you place your style in the resources section of your User Control, you can set the button style like so:

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyProject.MyControl"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:myclass="clr-namespace:MyProject">
   <UserControl.Resources>
      <!-- your style here -->
   </UserControl.Resources>
   <myclass:IconButton Style="{StaticResource StyleButtonBase}/>
</UserControl>
```

*(The xmlns 'myclass' must be replaced to refer to the namespace your custom button is in!)*

Also, if you remove the x:Key property from the style, it will apply to all buttons in scope, meaning you can omit setting it explicitly. This may be handy if you locate it in a shared ResourceDictionary (if you're building a library of custom controls for example) (if you do this, you will need to combine this resource dictionary in your App.xaml.cs file). If you end up doing that and you discover your UserControl doesn't have any especial functionality beyond wrapping an IconButton, you can of course omit it entirely and just use IconButtons directly in other controls. Your style declares how your IconButton looks, and your IconButton class ensures that the resources (your image) your style expects are there when it looks for them at runtime, so as long as your style is in scope, you're good to go.

Answer (score 0):

If the Style is defined in `Application.Resources` in App.xaml, or in a resource dictionary that's merged into `Application.Resources` in App.xaml, you can just reference it in the user control via `StaticResource`. If it's in another resource dictionary, you'll have to merge that one into `UserControl.Resources`.

Or you can put it directly in `UserControl.Resources` as TernaryTopiary suggests, if it won't be needed elsewhere.

As for the image source property, you could write a Button subclass as Ternary suggests, or you could write an attached property (see below). In XAML, when you customize controls, first you try to do it with regular attributes; then you try to restyle the thing. Then you escalate to replacing the control template, and that won't quite do the job, you consider attached properties/behaviors. Only if all else fails to do you resort to subclassing. You should know how to do it, but you should also learn the other ways of doing things.

In this case, there's a somewhat quick and dirty way to do it that's consistent with the correct XAML way of doing things: The `Content` property of the button is going unused, and its declared type is `Object`, so we can just use that. Since we're using a binding to pass in the image source, you can get rid of that `PropertyChanged` handler on `ButtonImageSource`.

```
<UserControl 
    ...>
    <!-- ... -->        

    <Button 
        Content="{Binding ButtonImageSource, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}"
        Style="{StaticResource StyleButtonBase}" 
        Width="{StaticResource DoubleWidthButtonSmall}" 
        Height="{StaticResource DoubleHeightControls}"
        />
```

And make the following change in the control template in `StyleButtonBase`:

```
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
            <Border
                Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                BorderBrush="{StaticResource BrushBorder}"
                BorderThickness="{StaticResource ThicknessBorder}"
                CornerRadius="{StaticResource CornerRadius}"
                >
                <!-- Now we'll find the image source in the button's Content --->
                <Image 
                    Source="{TemplateBinding Content}" 
                    Stretch="None" 
                    />
            </Border>
        </ControlTemplate>
```

### Attached Property

Using `Content` for this is a very mild abuse of WPF: You shouldn't *really* be repurposing properties. `Content` is universally understood in WPF to mean "any arbitrary content", not "any `ImageSource`".

So it's a little more "correct" to use an attached property, and it's not a lot more work. Here's how that would look.

We'll define the attached property in a separate static class, because I can't think of a good name for it other than `ButtonImageSource`, which you're already using in `SmallButton`:

```
public static class ButtonHelper
{
    #region ButtonHelper.ButtonImageSource Attached Property
    public static ImageSource GetButtonImageSource(Button obj)
    {
        return (ImageSource)obj.GetValue(ButtonImageSourceProperty);
    }

    public static void SetButtonImageSource(Button obj, ImageSource value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(ButtonImageSourceProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ButtonImageSourceProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("ButtonImageSource", typeof(ImageSource), typeof(ButtonHelper),
            new PropertyMetadata(null));
    #endregion ButtonHelper.ButtonImageSource Attached Property
}
```

In the XAML, the user control uses this attached property instead of `Content`:

```
<Button
    Style="{StaticResource StyleButtonBase}"
    local:ButtonHelper.ButtonImageSource="{Binding ButtonImageSource, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}"
    />
```

And the control template does likewise:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
    <Border
        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
        CornerRadius="4"
        >
        <Image 
            Source="{TemplateBinding local:ButtonHelper.ButtonImageSource}" 
            Stretch="None" 
            />
    </Border>
</ControlTemplate>
```

All the attached property does is give us a property that isn't named `Content`, and which is strongly typed as `ImageSource`, which we can use to pass in that image source.

---

Another thing: Maybe this was an error that crept in when you simplified your code for the question, but you're passing `typeof(TextOutput)` to `DependencyProperty.Register()` where you should be passing `typeof(ButtonSmall)`. More importantly, you've got two names for what should be a single property: `ButtonImage` and `ButtonImageSource`.

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty ButtonImageSourceProperty
    = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "ButtonImageSource", 
        typeof(ImageSource), 
        //  Should be ButtonSmall, not TextOutput
        typeof(ButtonSmall), 
        new PropertyMetadata(null));

public ImageSource ButtonImageSource
{
    get { return (ImageSource)GetValue(ButtonImageSourceProperty); }
    set { SetValue(ButtonImageSourceProperty, value); }
}
```

Incidentally, in your Style, it would be better practice to use `TemplateBinding` for `BorderBrush` and `BorderThickness`, and set the defaults in Style setters, the way you did with `Background`.

Comment: thx for your response! i updated my question, to make my problem more clear